# Reverting from a newer version of WordPress to an older version

Tags: updates, wordpress-version

For some reasons I need to degrade WordPress version of a site (I understand that it is **not** a good practice to do and I can fall into many troubles by doing so) but I still need to do it for some reasons.

I want to degrade from 3.0 to 2.9. I tried to upload the `wp-admin` folder of WordPress 2.9 installation into my WordPress 3.0 site but it was unable to load all the files. I can not delete the upgraded version as it contains images of posts.

Is there any way to revert back to 2.9? Moreover, is there a plugin that can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, downgrading would be a bad practice and is not at all recommended. Please make a backup of your database before continuing, just to play safe.

It looks like you've only replaced `wp-admin` folder. WordPress updates are not limited to `wp-admin` folder. 
Try replacing `wp-admin`, `wp-includes` and all those files in the root directory.

Now clear your cookies and goto:

> yoursite.tld/wp-admin/upgrade.php

WordPress might ask you to *upgrade* your database and continue with it. After this, you'd be running 2.9 (hopefully).

Comment: PS: make sure you dont replace wp-config.php in the root. New WP versions come with wp-config-sample.php and not wp-config.php, but do check.